# Open link in different browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Is it possible to open a link in a different browser? For example, our users are using Chrome, but we need to link to an intranet app that was built to run in IE only. Is is possible to create a hyperlink/Razor ActionLink that will open something IE after it's clicked on in Chrome?

Comment: Probably no good answer that works across all situations/OSes/etc. can you constrain the problem and provide more detail on your environment?

Comment: No, JavaScript won't be able to do something like that. One idea is to use something like a browser extension or Java applet

Comment: I would check to see if browsers typically register themselves to a URI scheme (for instance Spotify uses spotify:artist:xyz, maybe IE has ie:link.) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Psst… fix your intranet app

Comment: if you download a file of an unknown type, it will ask you if you want to open or save the file. you can choose the other browser to open it, and choose to remember the setting. You can then launch the specific app at any point by triggering a download.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Nope.

There might be hacks that allows this but you're on your own then.

*Update:*
Come to Think of it... it seems you are in a locked down Environment. There is a possibility every IE user has an application tied to a specific URI scheme (see comment on your q) which might open IE for its purpose. (say flash is installed for IE but not other browsers and you then ask for a flash specific URI - IE then opens) You can then do a clever hack to recognize where you are coming from or going to and do a double summersault and show the intranet site.

Remember that even though you cannot make the hack perfect it might work for 90% of the users and that is probably enough.

But I would instead take the whole subject to managers and tell them that THIS is why one uses standards and THIS is what happens when one doesn't program with love and THIS is why you should have listened to the geeks 10 years ago when you decided that IE6 is enough for everyone.
(I am still paying my debts since then - what I didn't push through in the board room back then I/we pay for now.)

Comment: There's no such hack. Just exploits for "dark-age browsers".

Comment: @oleq Don't be so narrow-minded. Of course there's hacks. The duplicate that this is of has ideas. It's no ideal, but browser extensions or Java applets *could* do this. That doesn't mean it's a good idea, but there are options